# How to resolve "No client method with the name 'newmessage' found" in an Azure Function with SignalR

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, azure-functions, signalr

I'm using React + TypeScript for the client and an Azure Isolated Function for hosting a SignalR hub. Before pushing everything into Azure it worked locally with finding the methods and passing messages, however, now that it's in Azure I'm now getting warning messages in the web console stating the methods are not found. The only real difference is running the code in Azure vs locally, and I'm not finding a good explanation in documentation on why that makes such a breaking difference.

Azure Function methods:

```cs
[Function("negotiate")]
public static HttpResponseData Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequestData req,
    [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = "serverless")] string connectionInfo)
{
    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.WriteString(connectionInfo);
    return response;
}

[Function("randomnumber")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "serverless")]
public static SignalRMessageAction RandomNumber([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo)
{
    int randomNum = Random.Shared.Next(1, 50);
    return new SignalRMessageAction("newRandomNumberMessage", [$"Current random AdminPortal number: {randomNum}"]);
}

[Function("broadcast")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "serverless")]
public static async Task<SignalRMessageAction> Broadcast([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.github.com/repos/azure/azure-signalr");
    request.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Serverless");
    request.Headers.Add("If-None-Match", Etag);
    var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.Headers.Contains("Etag"))
    {
        Etag = response.Headers.GetValues("Etag").First();
    }
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<GitResult>();
        if (result != null)
        {
            StarCount = result.StarCount;
        }
    }
    int randomNum = Random.Shared.Next(1, 10); // helps to visualize that the messages are going through
    return new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage", [$"Current star count of https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr is: {StarCount + randomNum}"]);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the client is constantly spitting out this warning instead of passing across the messages like I was seeing locally before pushing into Azure:

> console.js:213  [2024-02-07T16:47:45.199Z] Warning: No client method with the name 'newmessage' found.
> console.js:213  [2024-02-07T16:47:45.201Z] Warning: No client method with the name 'newrandomnumbermessage' found.

On the client I have two effects to build the connection:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
   setTestConn(new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('<signalr-url-here>')
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build());

   /* eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
}, []);
```

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
   const setupTestConn = async () => {
      if (testConn) {
         console.log('starting connection...');

         await connection.on('newMessage', (message) => {
            console.log('received new message:', message);
         });

         await connection.on('newRandomNumberMessage', (message) => {
            console.log('received new random number message:', message);
         });

         await testConn.start();
      }
   }

   setupTestConn();

   /* eslint-disable-next-line */
}, [testConn]);
```

The client makes a connection to the Azure Function hosting SignalR but it can't seem to find the methods. How should I be doing this in a way that the React client will be able to "find" the methods needed for sending/receiving messages?